# Which programming languages have JIT compilers?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, jit

I know C# and Java do. Anyone else know of any others?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strictly speaking, JIT is a property of the runtime, not the language. Pedantic point, but the implication is that any language that runs on a JVM for example can take advantage of the JVM's JIT. Jython, JRuby, Groovy, etc.

Tamarin has a JIT too. I think this can run JavaScript and ActionScript? Not positive...

Comment: Right. I changed the title of this question to reflect that fact, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/) has the impressive [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/).

[PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org/) has had a JIT for some time now.

I believe both of these are limited to x86.

Comment: LuaJIT for x86-64 is in beta and will be available soon.

Answer (score 5):

The [`Just-In-Time Compilation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) article on wikipedia lists several more:

- GNU lightning - A library that generates assembly language code at run-time
- Mozilla nanojit - A small, cross-platform C++ library that emits machine code. It is used as the JIT for the Mozilla Tamarin and SpiderMonkey Javascript engines

And several more assemblly emmiters for C++.

As for C# - all .NET languages use the same runtime and jit. VB.NET, C#, F#, IronPython, IronRuby, COBOL.NET and more...

Answer (score 3):

for Python, there is a [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy) project, which it includes JIT (making possible the code to run faster than in CPython in many cases)

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion on what defines/uses a JIT compiler: is it a programming language? is it a program ? a runtime environment?.

In fact, it is an **implementation** of a particular programming language which provides a JIT compiler for specific target instruction set architectures (x86, x86_64, PPC, ...).

For example, the SBCL implementation provides a JIT compiler for Common LISP, but other implementations of that language do not (such as CLISP).

Another example, the OpenJDK implementation of the Java virtual machine provides a JIT for some architectures, but not for others (such as ARM) where bytecode is still interpreted.

As a side note: don't forget the Factor programming language. The implementation heavilly uses a JIT compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Not a Julia expert myself, but it is a language that heavily relies on JIT. Many here assert that JIT is purely a runtime implementation aspect of the language; and that is how it was originally conceived. But the design of Julia as a language is heavily influenced and built around JIT, as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

C++ with extra libraries.

Comment: Specifically, Cling: https://root.cern/cling/ (LLVM-based) and the much older CINT: http://www.hanno.jp/gotom/Cint.html

Answer (score 2):

the .NET runtime uses JIT so any language hitting that. You can find more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation).

Answer (score 2):

Smalltalk has JIT compilers.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't use JIT. C# compiles to CIL for the .NET platform, and .NET uses JIT at execution time.

.NET is much more than just C#.  There's also VB.NET, Delphi.NET, Fujitsu Cobol, IronRuby, IronPython, F#, and more.  All languages that target the .NET platform make use of the .NET JIT compiler at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages doesn't use JIT. Programs use JIT.

C# doesnt have JIT C# is translated to CIL and CIL 'executable' is run JIT.

Dalvik uses Java's syntax, but is compiled to its own bytecode. Dalvik VM is totaly different than Java VM.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Dalvik. That's what originally motivated me to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

Julia has been designed from the ground up to work
with JIT compilers.

Answer (score 0):

PHP from version 8.0 has JIT:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jit